# Google subscription order id changed, how to identify subscription?

Tags: google-play, subscription

I am trying to identify google subscription entity in local db by orderId field, but I mentioned that the same actual subscription changed its id from `GPA.1111-2222-3333-4444` to `GPA.111-2222-3333-4444..5`

Is there proper way to ensure this is the same entity?

Answer (score 1):

This means the order is the fifth time the subscription got renewed

GPA.111-2222-3333-4444..0 (base order number)

GPA.111-2222-3333-4444..0 (Initial Order)

GPA.111-2222-3333-4444..1 (1st renewal of the Order)

GPA.111-2222-3333-4444..2 (2nd renewal of the Order)

GPA.111-2222-3333-4444..3 (3rd renewal of the Order)

GPA.111-2222-3333-4444..4 (4th renewal of the Order)

GPA.111-2222-3333-4444..5 (5th renewal of the Order)